# How to navigate to respective Profile screen when data is successfully added

Tags: react-native

```
useEffect(() => {
    if (customerAddUpdate.isSuccess) {
      dispatch(customerReset());
       if (props.route.params.mode === 'Add') {
        navigation.navigate(SCREENS.CustomerList);
      } else {
        navigation.navigate(SCREENS.CustomerProfile, { customerId: 
initialCustomerValues.aliasId || '' });
      }
    }
  }, [customerAddUpdate.isSuccess]);
```

I have written the above code to navigate to a different screen once data is successfully added, initially I wanted to navigate to list of customer screen once the customer is successfully created but now I want to navigate to that respective customer Profile screen once the customer is successfully added, can anyone please let me know how can it be executed.

Comment: Are you familiar with the Redux Saga? And, can you show us the code you're using to fetch/add data?

Once you resolve promises, you should navigate user to the specific screen. Saga itself gives you `yield` option for each async call (including storing data with reducers) so you ca easily navigate user WHEN data has been stored/proccessed.

Comment: Is it possible to use state?

Comment: You can add one more `useEffect` and put that particular state inside `[ ]` to watch for the changes and react if value of that watched state is complying to your request.

Also, you can add that additional state to the current `useEffect`. In that case, you should just check the value of that particular state with if-else logic to decide which action should be taken upon that state change.